# Resizing an image without loss of quality for different screen sizes. What is the best way to go about it?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, screen-resolution

So I am currently having some images designed for my app (social stickers Facebook style/ Line) I'm not really sure what resolution the images should be. iPhone 5s is 320*568 pts so a perfect square panning the width of the screen would be 320*320 points and because 5s is retina that would be 640*640 pixels. Is that correct? For a pixel perfect image spanning the width it would be 640*640 pixels?

I saw that iPhone 6 plus is 414*736 pts which scales up by *3 so it's 1242*2208, so would a pixel perfect square spanning the width for the iPhone 6 plus be 1242*1242 pixels?

If I was to get my graphic artist to draw on a 1242*1242 canvas would I lose much quality scaling it down for the iPhone 6 and the iPhone 6 plus?

Not really sure how to go about this. Just want to make sure my square canvas rescales without loss of quality between the 6+,6 and 5. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why is is 320*3 and not 414*3? http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Comment: you are right,  I thought the width in points was 320, not 414

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rescale from higher pixels to lower pixels it never lose any quality, so in your case yes you must ask for iPhone 6+ size of images to your designer and you can rescale as per your need, you won't lose any quality for sure.

```
width for the iPhone 6 plus be 1242*1242 pixels?
```

Yes you are right, you will need 1242 x 1242 for iPhone 6+.

Comment: So if you scale down a UIImageView it doesn't lose quality at all? If you were to scale down the png in photoshop it would lose quality though, right?

Comment: No you should scale down using Photoshop or Preview (Mac), you won't lose any quality.

Comment: Also you should use proper naming conventions for your images like @ 2x, @ 3x

Comment: Thanks for the video, clear about that now. What about if I want to make the image smaller in the app, say a thumbnail. Is it okay to resize in Xcode, let the UIImageView do the work or is it better practice to resize in photoshop?

Comment: No should never let xcode(UIImageView) to make it smaller, in actual it never scale it, it just fit bigger version in small UIImageView, which is not at all good for memory consumption. best practice is to provide separate images for all iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

if you are making a universal app, you will need Retina and Unretina versions of each image for both iPad and iPhone. That is, four different images:

For every piece of art, you generate four sprites.

```
iPhone Unretina: image.png
iPhone Retina: image@2x.png
iPad Unretina: image-iPad.png
iPad Retina: image-iPad@2x.png

Except for backgrounds, make iPhone Retina art the same size as the iPad Unretina art.
```

Extract from this article: http://www.gameartguppy.com/how-to-size-game-art/

Comment: am I right that the resolution for the 6 plus square is 1242*1242?